# XSLT, Transform template result to a variable and dynamically construct the new XML

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have an xml, expecting an processed xml via XSLT.
Here, I could generate the xml by applying template and now I want to use this template output as an input(dynamically) for the another input within the same XSL.

i.e. I want to pass the current output as input to the template output2.

Output1 : first Template, resulting R1
Output2 : second Template, needs to generate the final output.

**INPUT XML**

```
   <rules>
    <emie>
        <domain exclude="true">sww-epw3.testing.com</domain>
        <domain>sww-epw3.testing.com

            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:102994;AppName:Physical Records Management;StepOut:22 May 2015;StepIn:22 May 2016;Requester:Per Roseth;BusinessUnit:Upstream;PortfolioManager:Junfeng Liang">/Apps/dsprm</path>
            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:102994;AppName:Physical Records Management;StepOut:22 May 2015;StepIn:22 May 2016;Requester:Per Roseth;BusinessUnit:Upstream;PortfolioManager:Junfeng Liang">/Apps/uaprm</path>
            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:102994;AppName:Physical Records Management;StepOut:22 May 2015;StepIn:22 May 2016;Requester:Per Roseth;BusinessUnit:Upstream;PortfolioManager:Junfeng Liang">/Apps/ptprm</path>
            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:141923;MyRequestID:7512579;AppName:Production Revenue Accounting-PRA;StepOut:4 March 2016;StepIn:28 February 2017;Requester:PAUL.GEBBIE@testing.COM;BusinessUnit:UI;PortfolioManager:Per.Roseth@testing.com;Remarks:On Board Application">/apps/doto</path>
            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:;MyRequestID:7219068;AppName:;StepOut:9 December 2015;StepIn:;Requester:SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM;BusinessUnit:UA;PortfolioManager:;Remarks:Technical Assessment">/apps/seprm</path>
            <path docMode="7" comment="APEXID:;MyRequestID:7219068;AppName:;StepOut:9 Dec 2015;StepIn:;Requester:SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM;BusinessUnit:UA;PortfolioManager:;Remarks:Technical Assessment">/apps/gfprm</path>
        </domain>
    </emie>
</rules>
```

**XSLT **

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$R2"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:variable name="R1">
        <xsl:call-template name="output1" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="R2">
        <xsl:call-template name="output2" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template name="output2">
        <xsl:element name="DOMAIN">
            <xsl:element name="APEXID"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="MYREQUESTID"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="APPLICATION_NAME"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="URL"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="MODE"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="STEPOUT"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="STEPIN"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="BU"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="PORTFOLIO_MGR"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="REMARKS"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="RAG_STATUS"></xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL"></xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="output1">
        <xsl:variable name="site">
            <xsl:value-of select="rules/emie/domain/text()"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <emie>
            <xsl:for-each select="rules/emie/domain/path">
                <domain>
                    <xsl:element name="URL">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($site,text())" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@comment"/>
                </domain>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="domain">
                <domain>
                    <xsl:element name="URL">
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat($site,text())" />
                    </xsl:element>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@comment"/>
                </domain>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </emie>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@comment" name="tokenize">
        <xsl:param name="text" select="."/>
        <xsl:param name="separator" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:param name="separator2" select="':'"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(contains($text, $separator))">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="(contains($text, $separator2))">
                        <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(substring-before($text, $separator2))" />
                        <xsl:element name="{$token}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after($text, $separator2))"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:element name="AppName">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $separator)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
<emie>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/dsprm</URL>
        <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
        <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
        <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
        <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
    </domain>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/uaprm</URL>
        <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
        <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
        <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
        <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
    </domain>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/ptprm</URL>
        <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
        <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
        <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
        <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
    </domain>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/doto</URL>
        <APEXID>141923</APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7512579</MyRequestID>
        <AppName>Production Revenue Accounting-PRA</AppName>
        <StepOut>4 March 2016</StepOut>
        <StepIn>28 February 2017</StepIn>
        <Requester>PAUL.GEBBIE@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UI</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager>Per.Roseth@testing.com</PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>On Board Application</Remarks>
    </domain>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/seprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 December 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks>
    </domain>
    <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks>
    </domain>
</emie>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT- Need to include more new elements and process the data of input xml (output1) e.g date formating**

```
    <emie><domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks> <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
    </domain>
  <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks> <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
    </domain>
  <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks> <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
    </domain></emie>
```

Comment: What is your expected output? And why do you think it requires two-pass processing?

Comment: I want to add few more tags to the output1 and need to format the date as dd/mm/yyy.  `   <domain>
        <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
        <APEXID></APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
        <AppName></AppName>
        <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
        <StepIn></StepIn>
        <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager></PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks> <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
    </domain>
</emie>`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead. -- See also: [mcve].

Comment: The XSLT that you have posted does not produce the claimed output; it results in an error (Element name is not a valid QName). I am having trouble understanding what your question is.

Comment: I am using an online tool (http://www.utilities-online.info/xsltransformation) to test my XSLT aganist the input XML and its working for the above inputs and results the output1

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGJ

Comment: That seems to be issue with what I was selecting value , as of now I am trying to read the all the value.  I have altered the xslt - http://xsltransform.net/ejivdGJ/3 . thanks - @michael.hor257k

Comment: @michael.hor257k , Thanks for your help, your suggestion helped me !! Making Answer Thanks :)

Comment: @michael.hor257k Hi, Just if you could help, I'm held with another challange where my input xml contains -

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have upaded my question, could you please help me on this. Any help is highly respected .

Comment: Please post a new question with your new requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/rules">
    <xsl:variable name="site" select="emie/domain[1]/text()" />
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass-rtf">
        <xsl:for-each select="emie/domain/path">
            <domain>
                <URL>
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat($site, .)" />
                </URL>
                <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@comment"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
            </domain>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="first-pass" select="exsl:node-set($first-pass-rtf)" />      
    <!-- output -->
    <emie>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$first-pass"/>
    </emie>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="';'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="token" select="substring-before(concat($text, $delimiter), $delimiter)" />
        <xsl:if test="$token">
            <xsl:element name="{substring-before($token, ':')}">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($token, ':')"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As it is, it will produce the following output when applied to your input example:

```
<emie>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/dsprm</URL>
      <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
      <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
      <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
      <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
      <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/uaprm</URL>
      <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
      <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
      <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
      <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
      <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/Apps/ptprm</URL>
      <APEXID>102994</APEXID>
      <AppName>Physical Records Management</AppName>
      <StepOut>22 May 2015</StepOut>
      <StepIn>22 May 2016</StepIn>
      <Requester>Per Roseth</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>Upstream</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager>Junfeng Liang</PortfolioManager>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/doto</URL>
      <APEXID>141923</APEXID>
      <MyRequestID>7512579</MyRequestID>
      <AppName>Production Revenue Accounting-PRA</AppName>
      <StepOut>4 March 2016</StepOut>
      <StepIn>28 February 2017</StepIn>
      <Requester>PAUL.GEBBIE@testing.COM</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>UI</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager>Per.Roseth@testing.com</PortfolioManager>
      <Remarks>On Board Application</Remarks>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/seprm</URL>
      <APEXID/>
      <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
      <AppName/>
      <StepOut>9 December 2015</StepOut>
      <StepIn/>
      <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager/>
      <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
   <domain>
      <URL>sww-epw3.testing.com/apps/gfprm</URL>
      <APEXID/>
      <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
      <AppName/>
      <StepOut>9 Dec 2015</StepOut>
      <StepIn/>
      <Requester>SAIKAT.MANNA@testing.COM</Requester>
      <BusinessUnit>UA</BusinessUnit>
      <PortfolioManager/>
      <Remarks>Technical Assessment</Remarks>
      <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>somesite</APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
   </domain>
</emie>
```

To further modify the output, you only need to add templates matching the nodes you want to modify. For example, to insert a node after `APEXID`, add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="APEXID">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    <MyRequestID>7219068</MyRequestID>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Added:

> I cannot predict the token names of inout file.so i need to generate
>   an XML with uniform elements in the finaly XML.

To list the required elements explicitly, add the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="domain">
    <xsl:copy>
        <URL>
            <xsl:value-of select="URL" />
        </URL>
        <APEXID>
            <xsl:value-of select="APEXID" />        
        </APEXID>
        <MyRequestID>
            <xsl:value-of select="MyRequestID" />        
        </MyRequestID>
        <AppName>
            <xsl:value-of select="AppName" />        
        </AppName>
        <StepOut>
            <xsl:value-of select="StepOut" />
        </StepOut>
        <StepIn>
            <xsl:value-of select="StepIn" />
        </StepIn>
        <Requester>
            <xsl:value-of select="Requester" />
        </Requester>
        <BusinessUnit>
            <xsl:value-of select="BusinessUnit" />
        </BusinessUnit>
        <PortfolioManager>
            <xsl:value-of select="PortfolioManager" />
        </PortfolioManager>
        <Remarks>
            <xsl:value-of select="Remarks" />
        </Remarks>
        <APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
            <xsl:value-of select="APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL" />
        </APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Here I have an (input) xml with 1000+ <domain>  nodes. So my requirement is pass the processed result of my template (output1) nodes to an another template and format the date to dd/mm/yyyy , put some more logic on the elements of  processed XML (output1) elements. The resulting XML should have equal set of elements , then later tansform that XML to EXcel file. So here I need to maintain the elements for each domain.      Any help is appreciated !! - @michael.hor257k

Comment: @user1093452 I don't see where my suggestion contradicts anything you just said.

Comment: If you could have a closer look, e.g -their some of the domain node lacks with Remarks elements, So I need to have care on this and my default/required elements for the final xml should have elements of - APEXID,MYREQUESTID,APPLICATION_NAME,URL,MODE,STEPOUT,STEPIN,BU,PORTFOLIO_MGR,REMARKS,RAG_STATUS,APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL . @michael.hor257k

Comment: "*some of the domain node lacks with Remarks elements*" As I said, you  need to add templates matching the nodes you want to modify. So here, for example, you would have a template matching `domain[not(Remarks)]`and add the required node there. -- I don't know all your requirements, and I cannot make this stuff up. My answer is designed to take you to a stage where your input is the output shown above.

Comment: "some of the domain node lacks with Remarks elements" - Here I am refering to the output of the template i.e. Output1 but not with my raw input xml. So I am not able to match the template to check for availablity of remark element within the result of - <xsl:variable name="first-pass" select="exsl:node-set($first-pass-rtf)" /> . So could help to check for elements of -"first-pass" . Thanks in advance - @michael.hor257k

Comment: Apparently I am missing something here. If I look at the first `path` element of your XML input, I do **not** see a Remarks token in there.So of course it's missing in the result of the first pass, that does no more than tokenize the input and add the `URL` and  the `APEX_DATA_PORTAL_URL` elements. If you want to have it, you need to add it in the second pass. I cannot understand why this is a problem for you.

Comment: Exaclty the input xml lacks (Remarks as Token) here and I cannot predict the token names of input XML file. So i need to generate an XML with uniform elements in the finaly XML. Hence I was trying to validate the output1. Kindly advice how could we consume the output of template into an another. Thanks for any help - @michael.hor257k

Comment: "*I cannot predict the token names of input XML file. So i need to generate an XML with uniform elements in the finaly XML.*" Just list them explicitly in the second pass - see the addition to my answer. -- I suspect you still don't understand how this works. Any template you add to my stylesheet will operate on the XML stored in the `$first-pass` variable.